# Advanced Javascript form validation function

Tags: javascript

[This](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml#using) is what I'm using.

It's great. I only need to add function that checks if one of "cp", "bp", "hp" input area is entered or not. If not it should give an error that says "Please enter at least 1 phone number."

*(cp = cell phone, bp = business phone, hp = home phone)*

Comment: Advance is a verb. Advanced is an adjective.

Comment: function DoCustomValidation()
{
  var frm = document.forms["myform"];
  if(!frm.cp.value && !frm.bp.value && !frm.hp.value &&)
  {
    sfm_show_error_msg('The Password and verified password does not match!',frm.pwd1);
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    return true;
  }
}

Comment: That is what I tried, is that enough for you ?

Comment: @Extelliqent - Can you include that code in your question, with formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function checkPhones(){
  var frm = document.forms["myform"];
  var cell = frm.cp.val;
  var bus = frm.bp.val;
  var home = frm.hp.val;
  if(ValidatePhone(cell) || ValidatePhone(bus) || ValidatePhone(home)){
  return true;
}
return false;
}

function ValidatePhone(val){
//insert code to check phone meets your system requirements
//either length or pattern
//return true or false
}


frmvalidator.setAddnlValidationFunction("checkPhones");
```